# Rails newbie trying to understand why deployed Rails site has messed up formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

As a way of learning how to develop with Rails, I have cloned a rails app here

https://github.com/boxerab/redis-io

and have deployed to Heroku:

https://gigacrunch.herokuapp.com/

The original site is hosted here:  http://redis.io/

When comparing the two sites, the page formatting seems messed up 
for my Heroku hosted site.

Being a beginner, I am not sure how to start investigating why the formatting would be so different if the Rails code is the same.

Any guidance here would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Thanks, Pardeep. So, yes, I have no public assets on the site. I tried following the steps for rails 4 asset pipeline, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is clearly a problem with your assets, your css/js. If you use your devtools (chrome inspect element) on the page and look at the sources tab, it will show that the css file (http://polar-wave-5104.herokuapp.com/styles.css?1449091320 ) isn't loading. I don't know why, without more information, but that should be a place to start exploring.